# how to navigate two page back using popviewController?

Tags: iphone

I'm iphone developer. I got a problem that my first page is login page than home page. I navigate two pages from home page and now I want to navigate back to home but I can't come. if I'm using popToRootViewControllerAnimated then its come to login page but I  need to come to home page. please some one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

[[self.parentViewController navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];